# How can I make a specific piece of code portable for running on different systems through a pipe?

Tags: python, executable, binary

Quite often, when I search a solution to a problem, I end up finding lines of code like the following:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
```

This is a line of code that measures the speed of the internet connection that I'm using with a python script. I know that there are security implications on running lines of code like that without knowing what the code is doing on my computer. However, when I'm the one who developed a piece of code and I want to use it for personal use only, that's not a problem and it can be very handy because I can easily run specific functionalities that I create across different systems without having to worry about installing stuff on the system.

In this case, it's a python script, but judging by its size I assume that some library was integrated into the same script, just so it becomes portable for being executed like that. So, my doubt is: How can make a python code be integrated into a single file? Is there a command line for that? Let's say I'm using a specific library that's not a part of the standard libraries, like `geopandas`. Is there any way to automatically incorporate it on my script?

Could a binary solution make it even more portable across different systems? Just so I can execute code made on any language through a pipe like that?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could include them in your scripts, but I would advise strongly against it. Depending on the modules, your script will be huge.

You might also need a specific python version or other requirements.
Usually it is better to add a small `README.md` with prerequisites instructions and include [a `requirements.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457612/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project) to be easily installed via `pip`.

Then you can run like this in one go:

```bsh
pip install -r <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/requirements.txt) \
&& curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
```

or

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli.git
cd speedtest-cli
pip install -r requirements.txt
python speedtest.py
```

The latter would also make it easier to roll out updates of your software with a simple `git pull`.

(actually it's a bad example, because that repository includes an installation script and `README.md` explaining everything, but I simply ignore this fact...)